# calling exiftool from C++ in native windows

Tags: exiftool

I have successfully called EXIFTOOL from a batch file, but now I need to call it from a C++ MFC dialog (which needs to pass the results to another program). I have used "CreateProcess" to call EXIFTOOL, which appears to have worked, but I can't figure out how to retrieve the metadata output I requested in the comandline. I know it's possible to do it with Perl and using C++ in Cygwin, but I can't find any info for calling it in native Windows C++. Any tips would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The author of exiftool has a [C++ Interface for ExifTool](https://exiftool.org/cpp_exiftool/).  This uses exiftool's [`-stay_open` option](https://exiftool.org/exiftool_pod.html#stay_open-FLAG) which keeps exiftool running in the background.

Exiftool is not a program you want to call once for every file.  The startup time is it's biggest performance hit and calling it once/file can significantly increase processing time.  See [Exiftool Common Mistake #3](https://exiftool.org/mistakes.html#M3).

Comment: My problem is that (as stated) I am NOT running on Cygwin. My application is using MFC dialogs in native windows. EXIFTOOL runs fine from Windows batch. The stay_open option will be useful once I find out how to capture the EXIFTOOL output.